# How can I write a test for a WPF Command binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, commandbinding

I have a "commands" class:

```
public static class MyCommands
{
    private static ICommand exitCommand = new RoutedCommand();

    public static ICommand ExitCommand { get { return exitCommand; } }
}
```

Code-behind in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void BindCommands()
{
    this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(MyCommands.ExitCommand, this.Exit));
}

private void Exit(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

And some XAML in a user control that implements a menu bar:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Exit"
          Command="{x:Static local:MyCommands.ExitCommand}"
          />
```

The code works. I like the general pattern involved and I'd like to continue using it.

However, I am also trying to pursue some other goals, such as doing Test Driven Development and achieving 100% coverage with my unit and integration tests. I'd also like to have 100% conformance with StyleCop and FxCop warnings. And I'm caught here.

My `MainWindow.Exit()` method is private, as recommended by FxCop (Microsoft.Security:CA2109), but this means I can't call it directly from a test. I suppose I could make it public and suppress the FxCop message. Or I can use an accessor. But I have a bias against writing tests directly against private methods, especially in this case since all that does is test the method and not the command binding itself.

I feel like there must be some other way to invoke the command from my test code so that I can verify that the command works as intended (besides testing manually). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an old question, but I figured I'd answer in case it helps anyone else.

You can invoke commands from code-behind with this:

```
ICommand command = ExitCommand;

command.Execute();
```

This will execute Exit() and does not require an accessor. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Wow, now I know how to go about testing my View Models who solely depend on Commands (which are backed by private methods)

Answer (score 0):

Using a separated presentation pattern such as [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) will allow you to test the bulk of your code, including the logic behind commands. The views then become greatly simplified and less critical to unit test. I suggest you read up on MVVM and related patterns.

Comment: My code-behind event handlers will mostly be one-liners -- either simple UI logic (as in the example) or API methods on model code. I also plan to use injection dependency so I can mock things like Application.Current and verify that Shutdown() got called.

But I can't figure out how to trigger the Command so that my event handler gets run during my test. Like I said, I could use an accessor to call the private method, but I'd really like to use the Commanding system to verify automatically that everything is wired together correctly.